# Object files not properly added to archive on mac

Tags: macos, linker, fortran, archive, unix-ar

I am trying to build an archive from a collection of object files.
I am doing this with

`ar -rs my_archive.a foo.o bar.o other_object_files.o`.

On a linux machine everything is fine but when I try the very same command on my mac it seems like only some object files are added. This results in undefined symbols corresponding to subroutines in, let's say, `other_object_files.o`.

Moreover, if I try to manually link the object files that gave rise to undefined symbols, I can properly build the executable.

That is

```
ifort -o my_exec main.o other_object_files.o my_archive.a
```

works fine.

Am I missing some difference between linux and mac regarding this?

**EDIT**

From `nm other_object_files.o` the symbols look fine, so it is really like they where not properly added to the archive.

Here are some lines of the `my_archive.a`file in both linux and mac (the names of the object and archive files are different of course)

Linux:

```
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o:0000000000000000 T decomp_coms._
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o:0000000000000038 R decomp_coms___debug_param_const
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o:0000000000000030 D decomp_coms_mp_cwd_frac_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o:0000000000000008 D decomp_coms_mp_decay_rate_fsc_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o:0000000000000000 D decomp_coms_mp_decay_rate_ssc_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o:0000000000000010 D decomp_coms_mp_decay_rate_stsc_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o:0000000000000004 C decomp_coms_mp_decomp_scheme_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o:0000000000000044 C decomp_coms_mp_f_labile_
```

Mac:

```
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o: 0000000000000000 T _decomp_coms._
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o: 000000000000058c S _decomp_coms._.eh
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o: 0000000000000010 C _decomp_coms_mp_cwd_frac_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o: 0000000000000010 C _decomp_coms_mp_decay_rate_fsc_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o: 0000000000000010 C _decomp_coms_mp_decay_rate_ssc_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o: 0000000000000010 C _decomp_coms_mp_decay_rate_stsc_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o: 0000000000000010 C _decomp_coms_mp_decomp_scheme_
ed_2.1-opt.a:decomp_coms.o: 0000000000000050 C _decomp_coms_mp_f_labile_
```

**EDIT**

Tried also

`libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -o my_archive.a foo.o bar.o other_object_files.o`

following this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948807/static-library-link-issue-with-mac-os-x-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x8) but again no progress.

Comment: No success even if you use "ranlib my_archive.a"? (though the man page says "ar s" is equivalent to ranlib).

Comment: Following [this](http://docencia.ac.upc.edu/FIB/USO/Bibliografia/unix-c-libraries.html) I tried:

`ar -rs my_archive.a foo.o bar.o other_object_files.o`


 `ranlib my_archive.a`

but with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that apparently common symbols are not added by default.

Option 1:

`ar -rs my_archive.a foo.o bar.o other_object_files.o
ranlib -c my_archive.a`

Option 2:

`libtool -c -static -o my_archive.a foo.o bar.o other_object_files.o`