# Symbol not found when static linking on MacOSX

Tags: linker, clang, static-libraries

I am trying to create a static library and link it on MacOS X (several versions):
File `foo.c`:

```
char foo[111];
```

File `bar.c`:

```
#include <string.h>

extern char foo[];

int bar(char *src) {
  strcpy(foo, src);
  return strlen(foo);
}
```

Create a library:

```
$ cc -c foo.c bar.c
$ ar r libfoobar.a foo.o bar.o
ar: creating archive libfoobar.a
$ ranlib libfoobar.a 
$ nm libfoobar.a 

libfoobar.a(foo.o):
000000000000006f C _foo

libfoobar.a(bar.o):
                 U ___strcpy_chk
0000000000000000 T _bar
                 U _foo
                 U _strlen
```

Create a small test program:

File `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bar(char *);

int main(void) {
  printf("foobarbar = %i\n", bar("123"));
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and link:

```
$ cc -c main.c
$ cc -o m main.o -L. -lfoobar
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_foo", referenced from:
      _bar in libfoobar.a(bar.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is the symbol not found? It is defined in `foo.c`? Shouldn't at least `ranlib` create an index in the library that allows a random order of the files there?

The same code works well under Linux (gcc), and also when the symbol in `foo.c` is not a char array, but an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a similar question: [Object files not properly added to archive on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595766/object-files-not-properly-added-to-archive-on-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1) which has [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617478/598057):

```
Option 1:

ar -rs my_archive.a foo.o bar.o other_object_files.o
ranlib -c my_archive.a

Option 2:

libtool -c -static -o my_archive.a foo.o bar.o other_object_files.o
```

It is `-c` flag that makes a difference for both options on `ranlib` and `libtool` respectively:

> -c
>
> Include  common symbols as definitions with respect to the table
>                 of contents.  This is seldom the intended behavior  for  linking
>                 from  a  library,  as  it forces the linking of a library member
>                 just because it uses an uninitialized global that  is  undefined
>                 at  that  point  in  the  linking.  This option is included only
>                 because this was the original behavior of ranlib.   This  option
>                 is not the default.

Comment: To me, this sounds not unintended: if one does not link a library member that defines a symbol - even if it is uninitialized there -, then the symbol remains undefined and causes a linker error. What is the rationale behind this? And why is this different between MacOS and Linux (GNU binutils)?

Comment: I can't say what is the rationale, unfortunately, and don't know why is the difference. I was also surprised by your example code and just did a research on how I could make it work.

Comment: Our of curiosity, why don't you use a normal `foo.h` with a normal `extern char foo[];` in it? Is it just for the scope of this question or do you write a production code like that?

Comment: The code is not mine (it is old K&R code), and I also rewrote to keep the question as short as possible. An additonal `.h` file would habe make it more complicated for the example.